# Dust.js partial not found

Tags: javascript, template-engine, dust.js

In a root dir there are these files:

- partial.dust
- test.html

in partial.dust

```
<ul>
    {#games}
    <li>{id} - {title}</li>
    {/games}
</ul>
```

in test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Test</title>
        <script src="dust-full.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="cont-tpl-page"></div>

        <script type="text/html" id="tpl-page">
            Console {nome},<br/>
            {>partial games=list/}
        </script>       

        <script type="text/javascript">
            var model = {
                name: "Playstion 3",
                list : [
                    {id:1, title:"gta"},
                    {id:2, title:"fifa 15"}
                ]
            };

            var tpl = document.getElementById("tpl-page");
            var cont = document.getElementById("cont-tpl-page");

            var compiled = dust.compile(tpl.innerHTML, "page");
            dust.loadSource(compiled);

            dust.render("page", model, function(err, out) {
              cont.innerHTML = out;
              console.log(err, out);
            });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

With this simple code i get this exception "Error: Template Not Found: partial". Why? All file are in the same root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dust does not automatically compile and include partials for you, even if the files are in the same directory. You need to compile `partial.dust`, then include the compiled file in your page with a `<script>` tag.

Comment: I found this to compile the partials (https://github.com/dmix/dusterjs). Do you know others?

Comment: If you install Dust globally using `npm install -g dustjs-linkedin` you can use the command line compiler: `dustc`